# Laravel Passport Vs Laravel Sactum

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

#### Description

Currently, all my clients project was builded using `Laravel Passport` but recently I had read about the `Laravel Sactum`. It sounds similar to me.

#### Questions

I am getting really confuse? What are the main different between these two and in what scenario we should use each of them? Since we already have passport, what is the point of having Laravel Sactum? Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`laravel passport` follows oauth2 and is one of the implementations.

`laravel sanctum` provides a simple way for your authentication system for SPAs.

As you already used passport, there is no point to change to sanctum.

Sanctum is for the app that does not want to use the complex oauth2 flow.

Comment: make it in another way, does that means if our infrastructure only have mobile application, I am going to go for sanctum for simplicity. If my system consist of webapp and mobile app, I will go for Passport. Is that make sense?

Comment: @LAWWEILIANG, the word `webapp` is too general, if you mean `SPAs` (single page application) which may be hosted on a different server from your laravel backend. It's the same as your mobile app in terms of how the two apps communicating with each other. So if it's a new app and you want it simple, use `sanctum`.

Comment: @LAWWEILIANG, Does not matter what's your tech stack, Laravel Sanctum provides a featherweight authentication system for SPAs, (single page applications), mobile applications, and simple, token based APIs. So you  can use either, does this make sense for you?

Comment: Hmm, Andy. Noted. To be honest, my preference is more toward Laravel Sanctum rather than passport cause it is lean and simple. For maintenance part, new programmer does not require to understand oauth2, it save time as well. For my new project, I am to go for sanctum. Thanks Andy. Give you a like.

Comment: Opss, sure man. I forget about that step. Sorry bro. Hehe, thanks for your time. Appreciate that. :)

Answer (score 0):

#### To understand thing in dept

Article :`https://divinglaravel.com/authentication-and-laravel-airlock` 
Notes: `Laravel airlock(Old name)` and `Laravel sanctum(new name)`

Youtube's Explanation: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LELn-3ZpH9I`

#### My Summary (Benefits of Laravel Sactum)

1. If you are using spa(single page application, either vue, angular
   or react). Need not to include the bearer token into the request. It
   is automatically done after your first request to
   `/airlock/csrf-cookie`. The whole idea is turn the stateless http to stateful http.
2. If we have a stateless application like mobile application or
   others. We could easily create a stateless token using the following code.

> ```
> $user->createToken(
>  'laravel-forge', 
>  ['server:create', 'server:delete']
> );
> ```

3. Simplify maintenance part because programmer does not need to understand the concept of `oauth2`.

Comment: Agree. In passport you have to write your own login which may use different mechanism than original login method